# serialize form selected selectbox option on multiple selectboxes

Tags: jquery

I have multiple select boxes on the page all of which share the same beginning parts of the name attribute. What I need to do is go through each select box on the page with this starting name `SELECT___` and grab the name of that select box and whatever the selected option value is and have it formatted like this so that I can then insert it into an Ajax post call as shown below.

Note: the product code is retrieved from the following variable

```
var global_Current_ProductCode = '100E';
```

This is the Ajax call. Notice I hard coded the data field and it works but I need to grab the actually selected options value with its corresponding select name.

```
$.ajax({
url: $("form[name='MainForm']").attr('action'),
data: "SELECT___100E___7=25&SELECT___100E___9=42&btnupdateprice.x=0&btnupdateprice.y=0&ProductCode=100E",
type: 'POST', 
cache: false,
success: function(response) {
result2= $(response).find(".pricecolor .price");
alert(result2.text());
}
});
```

Here is the select boxes. Please note that there could be one, two or more select boxes on the page. Thanks for any help. Hope I am making sense.

```
<select onChange="change__option(this.name,this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)" name="SELECT___100E___7">
<option value="0">Select Cart Color</option>
<option value="21">Chrome</option>
<option value="25">Beige/Almond [Add $1.00]</option>
</select>

<select onChange="change__option(this.name,this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)" name="SELECT___100E___9">
<option value="0">Select Cart Color</option>
<option value="27">Red</option>
<option value="42">Beige/Almond [Add $2.00]</option>
</select>
```

So to sum it up I need the format to be like `SELECT___100E___7=25&SELECT___100E___9=42&btnupdateprice.x=0&btnupdateprice.y=0&ProductCode=100E` so that I can put it in the data field of the Ajax call. This is assuming that the first select box had the beige/Almond option selected (25) and the second select box also had the beige/almond option (42) selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jQuery serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). It simply needs an `id` attribute on the surrounding `<form>`. To include other information with the request, such as the product id or price, create corresponding `hidden` fields and call

```
$.ajax({ 

//..

data: $("#form-id").serialize(), 

//..

});
```

Comment: That kinda worked but didn't include the &btnupdateprice.x=0&btnupdateprice.y=0 so I added this to it and it worked perfectly.    data: $("#form-id").serialize()+'&btnupdateprice.x=0&btnupdateprice.y=0',

Comment: Actual selector used was this $("form[name='MainForm']").serialize()+'&btnupdateprice.x=0&btnupdateprice.y=0',

Comment: @user357034: The serialize() function grabs values only from input elements. To include additional information, you either need to add a couple of hidden fields or simply concatenate the additional data like you did.